# How to assign floats to some fields of json dumps using a for loop

Tags: python, json

I would like to create a json dumps which contain at some point data (here value) I should get from a for loop:

```
Dumps = {
         "field1": value1,
         "field2": value2,
         "field3":{.
                   .
                   "field33":[{
                               "param331": value, "param332": value,
                               "param331": value, "param332": value,
                               "param331": value, "param332": value 
                                }]
                   }
         }
```

I have the values of param331 and param332 stored in an array
but did not figure out how to extract them from the array myTab,assign them to their fields and keepo the required format.
I've tried

```
 ..."field33":[{
                for i in range (0, len(myTab)):
                      "param331": myTab[i]-5.0,"param332":myTab[i]+5.0,      
                }]
```

but this is not acceptable, I have also tried to create field33 outside of Dumps but which structure or type ? If the same assignment is out of Dumps I got: cannot concatenate 'str' ("param331") and 'float' (values of myTab) objects.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Dictionary and JSON object keys must be unique; your repeated `param331` and `param332` keys won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither a Python dictionary nor a JSON object support repeated keys. Your options are to create separate dictionaries or have all values listed together in a list, instead.

Creating separate dictionaries in your list can be done with a list comprehension:

```
[{"param331": tab - 5.0, "param332": tab + 5.0} for tab in myTab]
```

which produces a list of dictionaries:

```
[{"param331": value, "param332": value},
 {"param331": value, "param332": value},
 {"param331": value, "param332": value}]
```

one for each entry in the `myTab` list.

If you wanted *one* dictionary with just the two keys, produce lists as values for those keys:

```
[{"param331": [tab - 5.0 for tab in myTab], 
  "param332": [tab + 5.0 for tab in myTab]}]
```

This uses two list comprehensions, and produces:

```
[{"param331": [value, value, value], "param332": [value, value, value]}]
```